# Line splitter for 230VAC in the UK?

Tags: current-measurement, tools

In the U.S. where I am from, my company's field techs are required to measure AC wall current of our products frequently. To to this, they either make their own harness with a Hot (Line) wire to clamp on to or they opt to use a commercial line splitter like this: 
[image: line splitter]

The problem is that field techs in the UK are adamant that they are not comfortable using a homemade version and I can't find any commercially available. Does anyone know where to buy one of these using 230 VAC UK style plugs? Sorry for such a silly question, but I'm really stumped.

Comment: https://www.cef.co.uk/catalogue/products/4350349-ac-line-splitter 30second Google...

Comment: @JonRB I did 30 min. of searching as did another colleague and found nothing. Google I suppose filters by location (USA) despite our best efforts. Why didn't you make this an answer? This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: He's unlikely to make it an answer because he probably knows that *shopping is off-topic*.

Comment: Amazon UK has a similar product for GBP 11.99, rather mixed reviews.

Comment: You need to improve your Google Fu :). The reason I didn't make it an answer was the android app is rubbish,

Comment: @brhans usually yes, but the query was does such things exist in the UK. Such things are usually part of a more complete PAT setup so I wasn't sure if a single existed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is:

https://www.cef.co.uk/catalogue/products/4350349-ac-line-splitter

[image]

The Google phase was "uk ac line splitter"